# How to line up objects along a drawn line?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to do the following:
at the bottom of the screen there is a small window for drawing a line, in the center of the screen there are objects that line up in the drawn line

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDvis.png)

I apologize for my drawings :)

1. How to make this drawing window?
2. How to make objects line up in a drawn line?
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? The QA format of stackoverflow works best with fairly specific questions. So questions like "I want to do complicated thing X, please give code" are typically not well received.

Comment: I am a beginner and I do not need a ready-made solution or code, I need ideas on how to implement it and with what tools.

Comment: Any algorithm lining up objects along a line works on a specific representation of the line. E.g., the line could be made up of short straight line segments. Show us your code that represents these lines. Then only we can give you further advice on the lining up problem.

Comment: Get the equation for the line, get the number of objects you want to place, get the line length, and then space your objects along the line. When you ask how to make a drawing window and how to line things up you're asking too much.